# Maintain text-align: left and center

Tags: html, css

I have built the following page header which is vertically aligned to the center.

```css
h1 span {
  display: block;
}
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: table;
  background: #ccc;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    <header>
      <h1>
        <span>First line</span>
        <span>Second line</span>
      </h1>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to align the `<h1>` text to the center, but maintain `text-align: left`, like so:

[image]

I know this is possible by adding:

```css
h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 156px;  
}
```

However, the text is different on each page, so the `width` would need to be automatically detected. Is there a way to do this, preferably without Javascript?

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a solution that works in IE9+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `flexbox` for this, `align-items` to center vertically (the cross-axis) and `justify-content` to center along the line

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <header>
    <h1>
        <span>First line</span>
        <span>Second line</span>
      </h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** For IE9+:

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: table;
  text-align: center
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: block;
  text-align:left
}
header {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <header>
    <h1>
        <span>First line</span>
        <span>Second line</span>
      </h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it needs to work in IE9+.

Comment: It's really tough to pick when you get so many good answers, especially if they are the same. I've gone with yours as you've added a `flexbox` solution which I think will benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

Set the wrapping `h1` to `display:inline-block` and center that with `text-align:center` on the parent div.

Then `text-align:left` on the inner `span` aligns the text as required.

```css
h1 span {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: table;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    <header>
      <h1>
        <span>First line</span>
        <span>Second line</span>
      </h1>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    <header>
      <h1>
        <span>First line</span>
        <span>Second line</span>
      </h1>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 span {
  display: block;
}
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: table;
  background: #ccc;
}
.center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
h1{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more succinctly:

```css
header {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    First line<br/>
    Second line
  </h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use follow css :

```css
h1{position:relative; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(0); -o-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(0); -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(0); -o-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(0); -ms-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(0); -moz-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(0); text-align:left}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe get it working as a code snippet?

Comment: There is is one thing was remaining in css : "display:inline-block"